# Run a .sh script in subfolders

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing

I would like to run a .sh script present in each subfolder named Gex_experiments 
according to the following folder structure:

> ```
> Folder1       
> --FolderA    
>   --Gex_experiments     
> --FolderB     
>  --Gex_experiments     
> --FolderC    
>  --Gex_experiments    
> .......      
> --FolderAYCD
>  --Gex_experiments
> ```

To run the .sh script present in the first level of subfolders (FolderA, FolderB, FolderC, ...) in the past I used the following script:

```
for i in *;   
do     
    cd $i;   
    qsub myscript.sh;    
    cd ..;    
done
```

but now I'm not able to enter in the subfolders Gex_experiments where in this case the script I would like to run is present.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start in `Folder1`, you could do:

```
for i in */
do
    (cd "$i"Gex_experiments && qsub myscript.sh)
done
```

The trailing slash `*/` means that only directories will be found. The `( )` surrounding the loop mean that the command is run within a subshell, so you don't need to `cd` back out.

Comment: @Elb happy to help a fellow `qsub`ber (as long as you're not in the same queue as me! ;)